# How to run dotnet app online?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

I developed a console application using `NetCore 2.0`, this working really well on my linux distribution if I execute: `dotnet name.dll` but I'm not able to find any tutorial that explain how to run this console app online.

I'm looking for a solution that allow me to run the software 24h because my application need to store data into mysql database.

I saw that are different website that offer an `ASP.NET` cheap hosting but I don't know which service I should buy for achieve something like that, someone could help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy your application you need to be running it and redirect the HTTP traffic to the Kestrel Web Server by setting up a reverse proxy.

**Windows and IIS**

First, make sure your application is running using the Kestrel Web server by adding this configuration to your Program class (should probably already be there):

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

The above configuration will set up a reverse proxy and **run the Kestrel server automatically** for you.

For more info check [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x) and [ASP.NET Core Web Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x).

**Linux and Nginx or Apache**

You need to manually configure the reverse proxy to redirect the traffic to your running Kestrel server. If you want to **start the server automatically**, you need to configure a service:

Here are some instructions if you are using CentOS (or any RedHat based distro):

Create the service configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/kestrel-name.service
```

Edit the file with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=My awesome .NET Core Website

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/aspnetcore/your_website
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/dotnet /var/aspnetcore/your_website/name.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if dotnet service crashes
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
# Change this to match the user running your Web server
User=apache
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save and close the file an run the following commands to install and start the service:

```
systemctl enable kestrel-name.service
systemctl start kestrel-name.service
```

If you are using a debian based distro such as ubuntu:

Create a configuration file for your service in /etc/init/

```
sudo nano /etc/init/kestrel-name.conf
```

Add the following contents to the configuration file:

```
# My awesome .NET Core Website service configuration
start on filesystem
exec /usr/local/bin/dotnet /var/aspnetcore/your_website/name.dll
```

Save the file and run the following commands to install and start the service:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init/kestrel-name.conf /etc/init.d/my_website_name

sudo service my_website_name start
```

The following links explain how to configure the reverse proxy:

[Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

[Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Apache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Comment: Like your answer, but it's not very clear for me why I need Kestrel, shouldn't my application run normally as it does already on linux? Why I need Kestrel? Which type of server should I buy? Which you suggest? Thanks.

Comment: When you execute dotnet run and a server starts, this is Kestrel, but of course is a pain to run this manually every time, so you need to configure a service like explained in the answer.

Comment: Okay now is clear! This is amazing, I never did this before. I'm just setting up the `IWebHostBuilder`, I have installed this dependencies on my project: `Microsoft.AspNetCore and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel`, but I have a problem on `.UseStartup<Startup>();` the compiler say: `The type or namespace Startup could not be found` what I did wrong?

Comment: Do you have a Startup.cs file in your project?

Comment: Nope, I have `Program.cs` with a `Main` that execute the app

Comment: See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.0